# Selecionar a primeira linha de cada grupo em MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, distinct

Suponha que eu tenha uma tabela assim:

```
item   | group
-------+--------
item a | group x
item b | group y
item c | group y
item d | group x
item e | group z
```

E que eu queira selecionar um único item para representar cada grupo.

Agora, você deve estar pensando: "Tá, mas qual item? Porque cada grupo tem vários!"

Então, é regra é o seguinte: Eu quero, simplesmente, ordenar a minha tabela em função de alguma coluna, que neste caso específico será a coluna item, e depois associar a primeira linha de cada grupo ao próprio grupo, através do comando GROUP BY (ou outro mais adeuado).

Então, após a ordenação, ficaria assim:

```
ORDER BY item DESC

item   | group
-------+--------
item e | group z
item d | group x
item c | group y
item b | group y
item a | group x
```

E agrupando em função da coluna grupo, deveria ficar assim:

```
GROUP BY group

item   | group
-------+--------
item e | group z
item d | group x
item c | group y
```

Mas não fica! Sempre que eu tento fazer esses comandos, o MySQL ignora o comando de ordenação e agrupa como se a tabela não tivesse sido reoordenada antes, ficando agrupada assim:

```
item   | group
-------+--------
item a | group x
item b | group y
item e | group z
```

PS1: Vi alguns soluções desse problema através do comando OVER e PARTITION BY. Mas eles não funcionam no MySQL.

PS2: Note que a minha tabela não tem numbers, apenas strings. Com números poderia ser mais fácil, mas a intenção é generalizar a solução pra string mesmo.

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Consegue melhorar a pergunta, e postar sua querie. Talvez possa ajudar!

Comment: Talvez eu esteja simplificando demais o problema, mas me parece que você simplesmente querendo o "maior" item de cada grupo. Algo como `SELECT MAX(item), grupo FROM tabela GROUP by grupo` não resolve seu problema?

Comment: Rafael, desculpe se não consegui ser claro, mas, o Anthony matou a charada! É isso mesmo! A função MAX resolve a questão!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Criei um [**fiddle de teste**](http://rextester.com/BRQL1014) e a resposta dada em comentário por [@Anthony Accioly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/100/anthony-accioly) atende ao que você precisa:

```
SELECT MAX(item), grupo 
FROM tabela 
GROUP BY grupo
```

**editado:**

Considerando os comentários, acredito que [isto atenda](http://rextester.com/PZI77200).
Detalhe: a solução apenas estará correta se o campo `item_1` for único.

```
SELECT item_1, item_2, grupo 
FROM tabela t1 
WHERE t1.item_1 = (select max(t2.item_1) from tabela t2 where t2.grupo = t1.grupo);
```

Comment: Mas que diabos!!! Eu passei o domingo tentando coisas mais difíceis e esta simples função MAX foi a que funcionou! Brigadão hein! Mew!!! Valeu demais!!! Mas, deixa eu perguntar: E se eu quisesse a segunda maior? Ou a terceira? Como eu poderia fazer?

Comment: Não, pera, funcionou não!!! O MAX está pegando o maior da coluna item, mas e se o meu exemplo tivesse outras colunas item também (tipo: coluna_item_1, coluna_item_2, coluna_item_3)? Não necessariamente o valor MAX da coluna_item_1 vai corresponder a mesma linha da coluna_item_2 e 3.

Comment: Aqui, veja: http://rextester.com/BRQL1014

Comment: @JHenry podes dar algum exemplo? porque entendo que se tem outra coluna que controla quem deve ser o maior, bastaria colocá-la como coluna de controle (ex `MAX(coluna_x)` )

Comment: Eu errei o link. O certo é esse: http://rextester.com/TPJVRR39858
Note que no resultado da query, a linha da coluna item_1 não corresponde a mesma linha da coluna item_2. Isso tá errado. Eu queria as linhas se correspondessem, fossem a mesma.  Eu queria que o resultafo fosse assim:
item_1|item_2|grupo
------+------+-------
item d|item j|group x
item c|item i|group y
item e|item m|group z

Comment: @JHenry veja se resolveu ;]

Comment: É isso, é isso, é isso!!! Eu não entendi muito bem como você usou o Where mas o fato é que funcionou!!! Poderia me dar maiores explicações sobre o raciocínio da ultima linha?

Comment: @JHenry || `where t2.grupo = t1.grupo` -> vai pegar todos que forem do mesmo grupo (ex _group x_) || `max(t2.item_1)` -> pega o maior *item_1*.
Até então temos a mesma coisa da primeira consulta (`select MAX(it...`)) || `WHERE t1.item_1 = (SE...` -> isso consulta os dados daquele `item_1` específico, evitando de trazer dados aleatórios.

Comment: Muito bom!!! Você é freela? Pega projetos pela internet também!? As preciso preciso de uns dev pra me auxiliar, a gente poderia negociar pelo 99freela...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82313/discussion-between-rlinhares-and-jhenry).