# Como selecionar aleatoriamente uma linha de cada grupo no MySQL

Tags: mysql

Suponha que eu tenha uma tabela assim:

```
item   | group
-------+--------
item a | group z
item b | group y
item c | group y
item d | group x
item e | group z
item f | group x
```

E que agora eu queira selecionar aleatoriamente um único item para representar cada grupo, de modo que, após a reordenação aleatória e o agrupamento, o resultado fique assim:

```
item   | group
-------+--------
item b | group y
item d | group x
item e | group z
```

Ou assim:

```
item   | group
-------+--------
item b | group y
item a | group z
item d | group x
```

Ou assim:

```
item   | group
-------+--------
item f | group x
item e | group z
item c | group y
```

Tudo embaralhado e agrupado. Como posso fazer isso?

PS1: Note que:
- hora o grupo x está associado ao item d e outrora ao item f;
- hora o grupo y está associado ao item b e outrora ao item c;
- hora o grupo z está associado ao item a e outrora ao item e;

PS2: Se for possível seguir a linha de raciocínio desse post aqui, é melhor: [Selecionar a primeira linha de cada grupo em MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/325131/selecionar-a-primeira-linha-de-cada-grupo-em-mysql) senão, sem problema nenhum!

PS3: Já vi explicações similares usando o comando HOVER e PARTITION. Mas esses comandos não existem no MySQL. Então, preciso de ajuda mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Resolvendo

Uma forma de fazer:

```
select (select t2.item from tabela t2 
        where t2.grupo = t1.grupo order by rand() limit 1) as item,
t1.grupo
from tabela t1
group by grupo
order by rand()
```

---

#### Explicando

O que fiz foi uma *sub-query* que busca de forma randômica na mesma tabela, referenciando o *grupo*, assim gerando uma **lista randômica**.

Nessa lista gerada, **agrupo pelo `grupo`**, e **ordeno de forma randômica**.

---

#### Observações

1. Caso fizer a execução de parte da *sub-query*, verá que irá trazer as vezes duplicado, mas não importa, pois a última *query* que será o filtro final.
2. Substituí o nome do campo `group` para `grupo` para poder simular, pois em alguns cenários pode dar erro devido `group` ser palavra reservada.

---

Veja funcionado no: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/200959/7) ou [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wrmZH5wEZZAGkovoB74hXr/0)

Comment: Boa dev! Super agradeço a sua ajuda!!!